# Why is this python code not comparing two date?

Tags: python, django

I have written this simple code but even when i update my post from django admin section `{% if post.is_updated %} Updated on: {{post.date_updated}}{%endif%}` this piece of code doesnt run(updated on doesnt show on blog)

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text='Enter Title')
    content=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) field

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def is_updated(self):
        if self.date_updated > self.date_posted:
            return  True
        else:
            return False
```

**article.html**

```
 <div>{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }} {% if post.is_updated %} Updated on: {{post.date_updated}}{%endif%}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare dates, you just need to import *datetime* then cast the datas you want to compare.

Also, considere using the "return [test]" patern:

```
from datetime import datetime
dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"  #see  datetime documentation for non standart format
...

def is_updated(self):
    return datetime.strptime(self.date_updated,dateformat)  > datetime.strptime(self.date_posted, dateformat)
```

Of course, you may want to make your fields datetime at initiation instead of using string. In this case, use strptime() in **init** and just do a

```
def is_updated(self):
    return self.date_updated > self.date_posted
```

Comment: @theDude Sry, it needed to be converted to DateTime type before the convertion. I've edited the anwser, here you go.